# Where can I see the name of the remote add repository and how to delete it?

Tags: git, github

I git novice  I typed too many names like `origin` for "git remote add `origin`  git@github.com:f/ps.git" so if I even delete the repository from git hub and try again to add the same command I am getting the error `fatal: remote origin already exists.` where I can see all these name i have typed and how can I delete them from git hub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list all the `remote`s using:

```
git remote -v
```

You can delete a remote by doing

```
git remote remove name
```

where `name` is one of the remote names, in your case `origin`.
So all you need to do (after verifying you want to replace the `origin` remote with something else:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin url
```

where `url` is the remote's URL.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do that :

1) run `git remote remove origin`

2) If you have too many remote, it may be simpler to edit the `.git/config` file in your repository, it contains all remote aliases. It looks like this :

```
[remote "pub"]
    url = ssh://blabla@somewhere/home/myself/git/ourproject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/pub/*
[remote "jco"]
    url = ssh://blabla@somewhere/home/jco/git/ourproject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/jco/*
```